# Umbraco: Youtube Video Picker With SEO Properties

Tags: c#, youtube, content-management-system, umbraco

I need to implement a requriement, that allows a content manager to pick youtube videos (only youtube at this point) as proprty for a document type and also include this video in RTEs.

Further the CM should be able to set SEO meta information for the selected videos.

The only idea i have at the moment, is to create a custom Media type, that takes the video url and then renders the video accordingly.

Is there any better/ easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the UTube package and the DAMP gallery both explained at this link:
http://24days.in/umbraco/2012/damp-gallery/

The available property editor and a simple multiline text field should be a strong enough combination to achieve your goal.

The DAMP gallery is a good starting point based on your description.

I hope this helps.  Any questions, just comment and I will see if I can provide more answers.